# Random Placement Object In Blender With Python

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, scene

I have 7 - 8 objects (items) in my hand. There is one room. I want to randomly distribute these items in the room. For example, let there be 2 scenes, 4 items in 1 scene and 4 other items in 1 scene. I need help on this.

Similar to :
[image]

Comment: How would you randomly distribute your objects ? What's the rule ?

Comment: Think of a room, I want to do the same thing on the stage, in reality, there are 8 items, but it will increase in the future and it will be difficult to place them manually, so I resorted to this method.

Comment: Well randomly scattering assets is pretty straightforward. But in your case you have to specify rules. Some objects should be placed at floor height, some objects must be placed against the wall, objects shouldn't collide with each other, etc. All in all it can become very complicated

Comment: It can be easy. but i have no idea about it, what can i research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it is use randomize transform.

Select all your objects you want to randomize.

F3 -> randomize transform

enter some values for location as you need it.

[image]